# XmlPullParserException thrown when trying to run groovy script from within a Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have two Jenkins jobs, one called **"UpStreamJob"** and the other one is its downstream job called **"GetUpstreamJob"**.

Upstream job is configured to kick-off downstream job as its post build action.
Downstream job is configured with **"execute groovy script"** option which points to a groovy script 
whose main purpose is to get the upstream job name that triggered it and then write the job name to a property file(which I am yet to implement).

**Groovy script :**

```
@GrabResolver(name='jenkins', root='http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/')
@Grapes([
        @Grab(group='org.jenkins-ci.main', module='jenkins-core', version='2.167')
])

import hudson.model.*

def writeToPropertyFile(){

    def causes = Run.getCauses()

    for (cause in causes)
    {
        printCausesRecursively(cause)
    }
}


def printCausesRecursively(cause) {
     if (cause.class.toString().contains("UpstreamCause")) {
         println "This job was caused by " + cause.toString()
         for (upCause in cause.upstreamCauses) {
             printCausesRecursively(upCause)
         }
     } else {
         println "Root cause : " + cause.toString()
     }
}



writeToPropertyFile()
```

The error I get in Jenkins console log is :

```
Started by upstream project "UpStreamJob" build number 11
originally caused by:
 Started by user xyz
Running as SYSTEM
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on Server123 in workspace D:\Jenkins\workspace\GetUpstreamJob
[GetUpstreamJob] $ D:\Jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.groovy.GroovyInstallation\Groovy-2-5-7\bin\groovy.bat D:\Asif\getUpstreamJob.groovy
Caught: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException
    at hudson.util.XStream2.getDefaultDriver(XStream2.java:109)
    at hudson.util.XStream2.<init>(XStream2.java:113)
    at hudson.model.Run.<clinit>(Run.java:2471)
    at getUpstreamJob.writeToPropertyFile(getUpstreamJob.groovy:10)
    at getUpstreamJob.run(getUpstreamJob.groovy:32)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException
    ... 5 more
Build step 'Execute Groovy script' marked build as failure
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Finished: FAILURE
```

**EDIT 1 : START**

Below is the error that the Jenkins console log shows, when I try running the script by copy-pasting the script's code in the **"Execute System Groovy script"**:

```
Started by upstream project "UpStreamJob" build number 15
originally caused by:
 Started by user Malick, Asif
Running as SYSTEM
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on SERVERNAMEXYZ123 in workspace D:\Jenkins\workspace\GetUpstreamJob
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Class.getCauses() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: getClasses(), getClass(), getName(), metaClass(groovy.lang.Closure), metaClass(groovy.lang.Closure), getFields()
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:158)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:162)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$checkedCall.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
    at Script1.writeToPropertyFile(Script1.groovy:10)
    at Script1$writeToPropertyFile.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:160)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:157)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:158)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:162)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$checkedCall.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:32)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runScript(GroovySandbox.java:162)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SecureGroovyScript.evaluate(SecureGroovyScript.java:368)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SecureGroovyScript.evaluate(SecureGroovyScript.java:312)
    at hudson.plugins.groovy.SystemGroovy.run(SystemGroovy.java:95)
    at hudson.plugins.groovy.SystemGroovy.perform(SystemGroovy.java:59)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1853)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:427)
Build step 'Execute system Groovy script' marked build as failure
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Finished: FAILURE
```

**EDIT 2 : END**

Please let me know in case I missed out on any details. Part of the logic is taken from the internet.

Comment: Try to create pipeline job and wrap function call in a node context: `node{ writeToPropertyFile() }`

Comment: Sorry, but I am required to do it through freestyle job. Both the upstream as well as downstream jobs are existing freestyle jobs. Does the error here have anything to do with the job type.

Comment: I don't have experience with Groovy in freestyle job. Can you try to create pipeline job (remove the `grab` lines then)? If it works, we could rule out some causes. I suspect the grabs.

Comment: Do you have "system groovy script" enabled? From my reading, this will be required to access Jenkins object model. In the examples of system groovy scripts they also don't use grabs.

Comment: I do not know where to find that option "system groovy script". How do I check if that is enabled or disabled

Comment: This is referred to at https://plugins.jenkins.io/groovy/

Comment: @zett42 I have tried your suggestion and updated the OP, under EDIT 1.